# The parameter value of aws rds is not applied

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, amazon-rds

We are using mysql 8.0 version of AWS RDS.
The problem is that the RDS parameter settings do not apply.

We want the following parameter settings.

---

```
Variable_name, Value

collation_connection, utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

collation_database, utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

collation_server, utf8mb4_unicode_ci

default_collation_for_utf8mb4, utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

---

But it doesn't.
It is set to the following settings.

```
Variable_name                 | Value              |

+-------------------------------+--------------------+

| collation_connection          | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |

| collation_database            | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |

| collation_server              | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |

| default_collation_for_utf8mb4 | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

What do you need to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a bug in RDS.
The bug was contacted by AWS, and it is said that it is being fixed.
However, there is no ETA.

Set it like this:

haracter_set_client              utf8mb4

character_set_connection     utf8mb4

character_set_database        utf8mb4

character_set_results            utf8mb4

character_set_server             utf8mb4

collation_connection               utf8mb4_unicode_ci

collation_database                  utf8mb4

collation_server                       utf8mb4_unicode_ci

default_collation_for_utf8mb4 utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

skip-character-set-client-handshake 1

init_connect SET collation_database = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci; SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an AWS Database Parameter Group in order to apply these parameter settings to your MySQL RDS instance. After you create the Parameter Group, you will need to associate your RDS instance with it for the parameter changes to take effect. Steps:

1. Create a new RDS Database Parameter Group
2. Configure the desired parameter settings within the Parameter Group
3. Modify your RDS instance, and associate it with the new Parameter Group

[See a step-by-step guide for configuring your MySQL RDS instance's Parameter Group and parameter values here.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-configuring-parameters-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql-part-3-parameters-related-to-security-operational-manageability-and-connectivity-timeout/)

[See more details about RDS Database Parameter Groups here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html).